# Selecting an element without an Id

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to select an element from my webpage...

I have inserted a control into my page and i need to set some values an element inside the control at pageload from c# code.. The thing is, as soon as I insert the control into the page... A prefix is appended to the id name... Because of that new name, my css definition won't be appended...

Is there any way to access this element from C# without the need to make it an Id?

Edit: To clarify what Im trying to do here. Im trying to make a generic control, which gets a width and height set to it's parameters. I need to set this manually to the element by adding a style attribute. I can't make the element an id, because this will stop the possibility of making it generic.

This is whats inside of the control... the fact is, I need the imageRotatorDiv to  be a class instead of an id. Otherwise i can't use multiple image rotators on one page.

But how can I select a class in a page from c# code? Is it possible?

```
<div id="imageRotatorDiv" runat="server">
   <div class="imageRotator">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rprImages" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgItem" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more clear.  Perhaps provide an example of what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define your style to a class name instead of id.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyText" CssClass="someclass" runat="server" />
```

html output

```
<input type="text" id="Something_MyText" class="someclass" />
```

css

```
.someclass { border:solid 1px red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery :

```
$("div[id$=MyDiv]").addClass("myDiv")
```

And you just need to define the myDiv CSS class. Or, to modify directly the style :

```
$("div[id$=MyDiv]").css("font-size", "14px");
```

[JQuery details](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue.)